# ModSecurity OWASP 3.3.2 breaking Nextcloud - cannot solve this one

Tags: owasp, nextcloud, mod-security

- Running ModSecurity 2.93, and OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS)
  3.3.2.
- Enabled the Nextcloud exceptions contained in `REQUEST-903.9003-NEXTCLOUD-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf`, and they are being loaded fine.
- Nextcloud is updated to the last stable version, and passes all checks.

However, ModSecurity breaks its functionality in many important ways.

I get several false positives in regards to the activity of the sync app on desktop, the sync app on mobile and WebDav in general.

This is entirely ModSecurity doing. Nextcloud reports no errors and disabling ModSecurity solves the problems.

My attempts to fix this have failed. In particular, adding the following rules to `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf` completely breaks Nextcloud functionality, and doesn't solve any false positives. Not sure why:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /remote.php/dav/files/admin/" \
 "id:10000003,\
 phase:2,\
 pass,\
 nolog,\
 ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=921110,\
 ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=980130,\
 ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=949110"
```

Samples from the ModSecurity Audit log:

```
Message: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_request_content_type}" against "TX:content_type" required. [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "956"] [id "920420"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by policy"] [data "|image/png|"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/255/153"] [tag "PCI/12.1"]
```

```
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator GE matched 5 at TX:anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "93"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"]
```

```
Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf"] [line "91"] [id "980130"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Inbound Score: 5 - SQLI=0,XSS=0,RFI=0,LFI=0,RCE=0,PHPI=0,HTTP=0,SESS=0): individual paranoia level scores: 5, 0, 0, 0"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "event-correlation"]
```

```
Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 273] [level 3] [client <ip>] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_request_content_type}" against "TX:content_type" required. [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "956"] [id "920420"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by policy"] [data "|image/png|"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/255/153"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "<hostname>"] [uri "/index.php/apps/files/"] [unique_id "Y8Yq5sm-7UrRygrbZZNbsgAAABc"]
```

```
Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 273] [level 3] [client <ip>] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator GE matched 5 at TX:anomaly_score. [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "93"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "<hostname>"] [uri "/index.php/apps/files/"] [unique_id "Y8Yq5sm-7UrRygrbZZNbsgAAABc"]
```

The message in the Android sync app is usually "you are not permitted to upload to this folder". In general all sync apps are stumped by the 403 error provided by ModSecurity. I am not positive this isn't happening only for certain file types or certain folders, or, as I think, for all files.

Answer (score 1):

CRS Dev-On-Duty here. You seem to have two issues with your tuning rules.

The first issue is that you're using the control statement `ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=921110` without specifying a target after the rule. Either specify a target with `ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=9xxxxx;ARGS:myArg` or only remove the rule by using `ruleRemoveById` instead of `ruleRemoveTargetById`.

Second issue: never ever remove the blocking rule `949110` or the correlation rule `980130`. You switch off the WAF.

To solve your problem (I only see one rule that matched, besides of the blocking and correlation rule), I think it's best to add the Content-Type: image/png to the list of allowed request content-types. This can be done by uncommenting the rule 900220 in your crs-setup.conf and adding your required request content type:
https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.3/dev/crs-setup.conf.example#L422

If you need more tuning help, I highly recommend the tuning guide of our CRS co-lead Christian Folini, especially "Handling False Positives with the OWASP CRS": https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorial-8_handling-false-positives-modsecurity-core-rule-set/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried following your advice to no avail. I changed to ruleRemoveById for that one rule, but I stil get the same 403 errors. Adding content type hasn't helped either. On top of the false positives, the response time is incredibly sluggish. The only thing that brings things back to normal is to turn the engine completely off for Nextcloud.

Comment: Your advice was good, I had another error in my conf - see my own answer on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured out my problem.

I had this enabled in my `crs-setup.conf`:

```
SecRule SERVER_NAME "<hostname>" \
"id:10000001,\
phase:1,\
pass,\
nolog,\
setvar:tx.error_anomaly_score=4"
```

Which was an old attempt I had made to lower MS sensitivity, after reading about it in the MS handbook. Obviously I had made some serious misjudgment there. Things seem to be working now.

By the way: how to properly change the anomaly score for an hostname, so that MS is less sensitive? What's the normal value? I thought it was 5...

EDIT: Other problems in my log file, that caused sync with nextcloud to malfunction with certain file types, seemed to be due to a [new Nextcloud bug](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/34958) documented for version 25.

Comment: No. With this setting you define the score a rule gets for a CRITICAL rule. I would recommend that you read the really good docs, that explain the concepts behind the CRS and the scoring mechanism: https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/anomaly_scoring/ and after that the tuning guide mentioned above. CRS Dev-on-duty.

Comment: That was not clear to me. I didn't want to confuse other users.